# HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add not work in IE?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, cookies

I have function for mode switching

```
if (this.Request.QueryString["mobile"] != null)
    {
        bool isContrast = Convert.ToBoolean(this.Request.QueryString["mobile"]);
        var cookie = new HttpCookie("Mobile")
        {
            HttpOnly = true,
            Value = isContrast.ToString(),
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
        };

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

        if (this.Request.QueryString["returnUrl"] != null)
        {
            string returnUrl = this.Request.QueryString["returnUrl"];
            Response.Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
    }
```

And have checked

```
public static bool IsMobile()
    {
        string u = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
        var b = new Regex(@"android.+mobile|avantgo|bada\\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\\.(browser|link)|iPad|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
        var v = new Regex(@"1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\\-(n|u)|c55\\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\\-5|g\\-mo|go(\\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\\-(m|p|t)|hei\\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\\-c|ht(c(\\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\\-|\\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\\-|e\\/|\\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\\-w|m3ga|m50\\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\\-g|qa\\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\\-[2-7]|i\\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\\-|oo|p\\-)|sdk\\/|se(c(\\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\\-|shar|sie(\\-|m)|sk\\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\\-|v\\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\\-|tdg\\-|tel(i|m)|tim\\-|t\\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\\-|m3|m5)|tx\\-9|up(\\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\\-|2|g)|yas\\-|your|zeto|zte\\-", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);

        if (b.IsMatch(u) || v.IsMatch(u.Substring(0, 4)))
        {
            return true;
        }

        HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["Mobile"];

        if (cookie != null)
        {
            return Convert.ToBoolean(cookie.Value);
        }

        return false;
    }
```

This code works all browsers, but only at IE 9 not work, and I don't know how this fix

I used ASP.NET Web Form 4

**UPDATE:**

I forget to say about what this code work in IE only at local server

**UPDATE:**

How I understand Session to quickly dead. I check what at this page cookie and session have not null, but when I go another page, this object has null

**UPDATE:**

After change domain name from new.sitename to site name. Code began to work o_0

Answer (score 1):

If IE is operating in High security mode, or if the cookie you're setting is a third-party cookie (from a different domain than the URL in the address bar) with IE in the default Medium security mode, IE won't accept the cookie unless you also set a privacy policy HTTP header.

To test, try setting this very simple privacy header, in the same response in which you set the cookie:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("P3P", "CP = \"NID DSP CAO COR\"");
```

Also, use a web proxy like Fiddler to check whether the HTTP response and request headers look correct, including setting and receiving the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes IE's cookies get messed up, especially when you're constantly changing them as in development.  Try deleting you cookies and see if it works again.

Comment: I cleared all cookies IE and how I understand cookies do not created